# Measure the Length of a Line generated by polyfit() Using python

Tags: python, measure

I'm trying to measure the length of a 'best-fit' line with an order of magnitude 2 that I generated using the polyfit() function in Python, so that I can compare that length to the length of the original line.

I've tried importing shapely.geometry and using LineString and then .length, but LineString gives me an error given the polyfit() line variable.

I'd like to know if there is a way to measure the total length of a line generated from polyfit().

This is the code for the original line that I generated and measured:

```
negative5contour = contour(mgX,mgY,dem,levels=linspace(-5,-5,1))
pointsn5 = negative5contour.collections[0].get_paths()[205].vertices
linen5 = LineString(pointsn5[:,0:2])
print 'length of original -5 contour:', linen5.length, '(m)'


                                       length of original -5 contour: 961613.847282 (m)
```

This is the code I used to to generate the best-fit line of magnitude 2 for the elevation contour:

```
neg5X = pointsn5[:,0]
neg5Y = pointsn5[:,1]
plot(neg5X,neg5Y,'g')
fitneg5= polyfit(neg5X,neg5Y,2)
fit_final_neg5 = poly1d(fitneg5)
```

I tried using LineString and Length on fit_final_neg5:

```
n5Best = LineString(fit_final_neg5)

n5Best.Length
```

But the error says:

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-71-6b72c644625d> in <module>()
  6 
  7 
 ----> 8 n5Best = LineString(fit_final_neg5)


ValueError: Input            2
3.529e-06 x - 22.44 x + 3.614e+07 is the wrong shape for a LineString
```

Does Anyone have ideas as to how I can fix/get around this problem?

FYI: I am quite new to python.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Polyfitting with degree 2 produces a polynomial of degree 2 (i.e., a parabola), not a line.

Comment: I'm not working with Straight lines, I'm actually working with contours that resemble a parabola. 
The LineString worked with measuring the contours so it doesn't require the full line to be straight. I assumed it created lines between each of the points and then .length measured the distance between each of those points and summed it. So part of my problem might be that there's not enough points generated from plolyfit. Is there a way to get more points out from that function with keeping it a degree 2? Possibly another function I could on the parabola generated?